# How can I lower the ESXI acceptance level when a forced install has been done?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to install a `.vib` on an ESXi server. This specific one needs an acceptance level of 'community'. I tried to set the level from partner to community as follows:

```
 # esxcli software acceptance set --level=CommunitySupported
```

Which resulted in:

> [AcceptanceConfigError]
>    Unable to set acceptance level of community due to installed VIBs virtuallyGhetto_bootbank_ghettoVCB_1.0.0-0.0.0 having a lower acceptance level.
>    Please refer to the log file for more details.

If I list the installed software, that specific file is listed as:

```
ghettoVCB   1.0.0-0.0.0    virtuallyGhetto  CommunitySupported  2015-10-27
```

This does imply that the level I'm trying to set is *not* lower then it need? Digging further, it seems that this was installed by just adding -f to the install command.

How could I lower the acceptance level on this machine? Is there an official method, or at least a known issue with having a bit of software in there that needs a lower setting than the current actual setting?

Interesting is that as far as I could find out, CommunitySupported is the lowest level, so I can't set it even lower: my guess is the fact that it is lower then the current setting makes something go wrong?

Software running is:

> VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-2068190
>   VMware ESXi 5.5.0 Update 2

Because on this server I didn't even need that 'ghettoVCB', so I just uninstalled it; lowering the acceptance worked perfectly after that. 
**But this is obviously a workaround not usefull in all cases, so i'm interested in a real solution // what i *should* have done.**

Answer (score 0):

You can change it via the web interface. ### ESXi Host and go to Configure >> System >> Security Profile. Under "Host Image Profile Acceptance Level" view the acceptance level. Edit and then change it to CommunitySupported ### It worked for me on ESXi with installed GhettoVCB backup.